# Editor crashes when saving mesh that has many vertices

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assets

Editor crashes when execute `AssetDatabase.CreateAsset` to save mesh that has about 150,000,000 vertices.

---

I made a mesh object with C# script, and trying to save it with `AssetDatabse.CreateAsset();`. Here's my code for save asset ↓

```
AssetDatabase.StartAssetEditing();
AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(tempMesh, $"Assets/Export/{fileName}.asset");
AssetDatabase.StopAssetEditing();
```

I can save a mesh when the vertices of the *tempmesh* is about 80,000 (I already added `tempMesh.indexFormat = UnityEngine.Rendering.IndexFormat.UInt32;`), but the editor crashes if that is about 150,000,000.

I'm thinking of separating mesh per 100,000 vertices (making 1,500 meshes), then generate object for each mesh. But I don't want to separate as much as possible.

What can I do to save mesh that has about 150,000,000 vertices?

### Environment

- MacBook pro 2020, 13-inches, 8GB RAM
- Unity 2020.3.47f1

### Log

Here's the log when the editor crashed.

```
Obtained 46 stack frames.
#0  0x0000011048d0d1 in BytesToHexString(void const*, unsigned long, char*)
#1  0x0000011014044d in TextDOMTransferWriteBase<YAMLWrite>::TransferTypelessData(unsigned int, void*, TransferMetaFlags)
#2  0x0000011025898a in void VertexData::Transfer<YAMLWrite>(YAMLWrite&)
#3  0x0000010ff78f64 in void YAMLWrite::Transfer<VertexData>(VertexData&, char const*, TransferMetaFlags)
#4  0x00000111d3ab32 in void Mesh::Transfer<YAMLWrite>(YAMLWrite&)
#5  0x00000111d3a514 in void YAMLWrite::Transfer<Mesh>(Mesh&, char const*, TransferMetaFlags)
#6  0x000001106dabbf in void SerializedFile::WriteTextSerialized<Object>(core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char>>&, Object&, BuildUsageTag const&, TransferInstructionFlags)
#7  0x000001106da73e in SerializedFile::WriteObject(Object&, long long, short, BuildUsageTag const&, GlobalBuildData const&)
#8  0x000001106b9f6d in PersistentManager::WriteFile(core::basic_string_ref<char>, int, WriteData const*, int, GlobalBuildData const&, VerifyWriteObjectResult (*)(Object*, BuildTargetPlatform), BuildTargetSelection, TransferInstructionFlags, WriteInformation&, InstanceIDResolver const*, PersistentManager::LockFlags, int (*)(PersistentManager::ReportWriteObjectStep, int, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char>> const&, int, void*), void*)
#9  0x000001106b8b23 in PersistentManager::WriteFile(core::basic_string_ref<char>, int, WriteData const*, int, GlobalBuildData const&, VerifyWriteObjectResult (*)(Object*, BuildTargetPlatform), BuildTargetSelection, TransferInstructionFlags, InstanceIDResolver const*, PersistentManager::LockFlags, int (*)(PersistentManager::ReportWriteObjectStep, int, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char>> const&, int, void*), void*)
#10 0x000001110e11c8 in WriteObjectsToDiskThreadSafe(core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char>> const&, Object**, long long const*, unsigned long, TransferInstructionFlags)
#11 0x000001113e722f in CreateSerializedAssetV2(Object**, int, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char>> const&, AssetDatabase::CreateAssetMask)
#12 0x00000111382c9c in AssetDatabase::CreateSerializedAsset(Object&, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char>> const&, AssetDatabase::CreateAssetMask)
#13 0x00000111739d78 in AssetDatabaseBindings::CreateAsset(PPtr<Object>, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char>> const&, ScriptingExceptionPtr*)
#14 0x000001117d7b04 in AssetDatabase_CUSTOM_CreateAsset(ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*)
#15 0x000001b52959e5 in  (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEditor.AssetDatabase:CreateAsset (UnityEngine.Object,string) {0x7fc4732dab20} + 0x65 (0x1b5295980 0x1b5295a6d) [0x151982960 - Unity Child Domain]
#16 0x000001824d2fab in  Cysharp.Threading.Tasks.CompilerServices.AsyncUniTask`1<MainAsync/<tengunMeshGenerator>d__3>:Run () {0x7fc471c24c10} + 0x2b (0x1824d2f80 0x1824d2fcb) [0x151982960 - Unity Child Domain]
#17 0x000001824dd2cb in  Cysharp.Threading.Tasks.Internal.ContinuationQueue:Update () {0x7fc4729ea3d0} + 0x1b (0x1824dd2b0 0x1824dd2d0) [0x151982960 - Unity Child Domain]
#18 0x0000015683b1f5 in mono_jit_runtime_invoke
#19 0x000001569d9213 in do_runtime_invoke
#20 0x000001569d916d in mono_runtime_invoke
#21 0x0000011064c197 in scripting_method_invoke(ScriptingMethodPtr, ScriptingObjectPtr, ScriptingArguments&, ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)
#22 0x00000110647746 in ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)
#23 0x00000110323cd9 in ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*)
#24 0x00000110323b65 in ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*)
#25 0x00000110323fb5 in PlayerLoop()
#26 0x00000110e930c2 in PlayerLoopController::UpdateScene(bool)
#27 0x00000110e8d207 in PlayerLoopController::UpdateSceneIfNeeded()
#28 0x00000110e8a664 in Application::TickTimer()
#29 0x000001121bca3f in -[EditorApplication TickTimer]
#30 0x007ff805399766 in __NSFireTimer
#31 0x007ff8044e9358 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
#32 0x007ff8044e8ed3 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer
#33 0x007ff8044e8af9 in __CFRunLoopDoTimers
#34 0x007ff8044cee39 in __CFRunLoopRun
#35 0x007ff8044cdf31 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
#36 0x007ff80df49dad in RunCurrentEventLoopInMode
#37 0x007ff80df49bbe in ReceiveNextEventCommon
#38 0x007ff80df49918 in _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter
#39 0x007ff8075625d0 in _DPSNextEvent
#40 0x007ff80756147a in -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]
#41 0x007ff807553ae8 in -[NSApplication run]
#42 0x007ff807527d02 in NSApplicationMain
#43 0x000001121d856d in EditorMain(int, char const**)
#44 0x000001121d8799 in main
#45 0x007ff80409a41f in start
Launching bug reporter
```

Comment: That is one hundred and fifty million correct?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes, that's right.

Comment: Seems a bit extreme doesn't it? Assuming you could save it, how do you plan to render it?

Comment: Actually, I want to make a mesh of point cloud, so it needs a number of vertices. I'm planning to attach saved mesh to MeshFilter.

Comment: have you logged a bug with unity?

Comment: Well, I tried to, but i don't know well how to do that...

Comment: Hehe you never want that many vertices in Unity! Good luck with any PC loading .. not even speaking of rendering this. That's the reason why you triangulate and reduce point clouds as much as possible in order to show a more lightweight approximated mesh ...

Comment: After that, I found the way of using the "Graphics.DrawMesh", it works much better then what i did before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that it is due to a lack of RAM. Your device has a total of 8 GB of RAM, excluding space for system and different app operations. In this case, the total free memory may be 6 GB or even less.
I suggest checking the activity monitor while generating the mesh with 150,000,000. vertices, this will let you see if you have exceeded the amount of available resources

Comment: Thanks for your advice! As you said, the problem was a lack of RAM. Checking the activity monitor, the usage of RAM of Unity was almot 20GB. And I borrowed my friend's PC, which has 32GB of RAM, and it worked successfully.

Comment: I can't borrow my friend's PC all the time, so I have to reconsider of creating mesh that work in 8GB RAM PC. Anyway, again, thanks for your advice!